# Can we create multiple navigation controllers in iOS?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I am a little bit confused about navigation controllers. In one navigation controller, a large amount of view controllers are present. I have seen so many examples with one navigation controller. Can we create multiple navigation controllers in iOS and in each navigation controller, can we define a number of view controllers? Is it possible? Please, someone explain this to me and give some real world examples if this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the sample programs in the Apple documentation. The Navigation controller is a stack which start at the app delegate level. You push view controllers into the stack and pop them out when you are done .... going back to the previous level. You can poptoroot which goes down to the lowest level just above the app delegate.

You have the option to have as many navigation controllers as you have Tabs in a Tab bar. it is not confusing ... Apple has a set of good examples that illustrate them ... Believe the sample about Elements is one.